# Full-width horizontal gallery with scrolling for items outside of view-port

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a page layout along the lines of this:

[image: Layout]

The idea for the middle section is a full width (i.e. view-port width, as opposed to the page/footer content which are container width) horizontal gallery of items, each of which have a set height and width. How many items are shown will depend on the width of view-port. For the items that are not visible in the view-port, the user should be able to scroll through them by clicking the scroll button on the left or right of the gallery.

What would be the best way to create a gallery of items like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can have a wrapper set to have `width:100%;overflow:hidden` and a container with `white-space:nowrap;`. That way, by manipulating the `left` property of the container, you can scroll through items.

http://jsfiddle.net/kQnjY/

Answer (score 1):

I'm using http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel
It's very easy to use and has the possibility to be vertical , horizontal, circular..

Sample: http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/special_flexible.html